# How to print the number of nested types in Vector<> in Java?

Tags: java, vector

How to get the nested level of types in a Vector in Java ?

For instance:

the number of the nested level of `Vector<Integer> vec` is 1;

the number of the nested level of `Vector<Vector<Integer>> vec` is 2;

the number of the nested level of `Vector<Vector<Vector<Integer>>> vec` is 3;

...

The `vec` might be empty, is there any way to get this in Java?

Is it the only way that using `int getNestedLevel(Class<?>... clazz)` and `return clazz.length`?

How to accomplish it without pass all `Class<?>` ?

Thank you!

Comment: why do you need another way? you can have a recursive check, using instanceof or something similar

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why are you using `Vector`? If you're creating a parent-child-grandchild-etc relationship you're better off creating a bean `MyBean` which has property `ArrayList<MyBean> children`.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `Vector<Integer>` or `Vector<Vector<Integer>>` etc in Java at runtime. There is only `Vector`. The `<...>` is information the compiler uses to ensure type compatibility, and to insert casts if necessary. It's not available to you at runtime.

Comment: Ok, you got my answer. But you do know this at compile time anyway, or do you mess around with untyped stuff that you have to re-type at some point (I do occasionally). I mean, you could extract the number from the source code, but that's not what you want, right?

Comment: @Stultuske @Paul Hi, the scene is, I have a serialized buffer and the type `Vector<Vector<Integer>>` or `Vector<Vector<Vector<Byte>>>`, ..., no matter it is. I want to deserialize it. According to serialize algorithm, you can only parse the first dim Vector before getting the second dim Vector because the second dim and size info are in the first Vector(the first is in the buffer head). It is a recursive question.

Comment: I am a c++ programmer, honestly, and finding an easy way to accomplish Java serialization and deserialization algorithm.

Comment: PS: I don't know the deep of `Vector<Vector<...>>`, so I want to get it nested depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say, due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and the possibility that vectors can be empty you can't get at that. Next thing, if a vector is not empty, but contains an element of type U that extends its generic type T, you can get at U, but can't conclude T. Same if T is an interface.

You could extract the number from the source code, but that's not what you mean, I guess.